# Ubuntu 20.04 Wi-Fi very slow

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-20.04

I have a DELL Optiplex 7080 with windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 lts dual boot. Windows wifi is very fast as expected but ubuntu wifi is very slow (20kb/s). Also if I disconnect wifi then  it fails to connect again and fails until I remove and re-insert the wifi adapter. I am using tp link tl-wn823n adapter. How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230525/ubuntu-20-04-network-performance-extremely-slow

Comment: Yes, and tried every possible solution but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Have you looked into the driver version? With my newer tp link, I had to install the newer driver for it work correctly. This is a pretty advance thing to do, though. i.e. get the driver, compile it, load it, etc.

Comment: @AlexisWilke How can I do that? (I'm new to these)

Comment: @ArRakin It's a little different for each device. Here is a page from the company https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1076/ and a page from the kernel https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html and searching for others with your exact model may give you a page where some has done it for that exact model which is often the best bet.